# Why fs writeFile work only one time in heroku app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, fs

I have simple code to write file on server. It works on pc with out any problem But after i push it to heroku, it only works one time. When i want to overwrite the file it doesn't work. The code is below

```
router.post("/writefile/note1",function(req,res){
     const path = require('path');
     const filepathis = path.resolve('views/files', 'testwritebeg.ejs');

    var title = req.body.title;
    var date = req.body.date;
    var pagh1 = req.body.pagh1;

    var writethis = '<p>' + title + '</p> \n' +
                    '<p>' + date + '</p>\n' +
                    '<p>'+ pagh1 + '</p>\n' ;

    fs.writeFile(filepathis, writethis, (err) => {  
            if (err) throw err;
          res.render("files/testwritebeg");  
      }); 
 });
```

What i want to do is, from the app using "router post" i want the user to overwrite the files. But this works only one time.

I search many time about this problem. But i found nothing. Any help please. I am stacked.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be writing to the filesystem on Heroku. It is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem); at least once per day the filesystem will be wiped when the dyno reboots.

Comment: @RangerRanger After i buy domain it still will be a problem? After i buy domain name is there a limit to use file-system?

Comment: Regarding the above question  If anybody can have an idea or possible solutions i will be waiting.